# C# - ( Drawing Columns - Top Right) drawString issues

Tags: c#

As you can see in the image, this is the result. I would like to get the drawString to draw in the top right corner of the drawn lines

https://i.stack.imgur.com/clxbA.png

```
    public void Form_Outline()
    {

        // top left A 
        // top right B
        // bottom left C
        // bottom right D

        WriteLog("Start");

        WriteLog(string.Format("Height {0}",Tile_Grid.Height));
        WriteLog(string.Format("Width {0}", Tile_Grid.Width));

        Graphics gDraw = Tile_Grid.CreateGraphics();

        Pen Black_Pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5);
        Pen Red_Pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);

        gDraw.DrawRectangle(Black_Pen, 0, 0, Tile_Grid.Width, Tile_Grid.Height);


        int Column_Quanity = Int32.Parse(Vertical_Lines.Text);

        var Column_Seperation_Size = Tile_Grid.Width / Column_Quanity;
        var Column_Count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < Column_Quanity; i++)
        {
            Column_Count += Column_Seperation_Size;

            WriteLog(i.ToString());

            if (!(i == (Column_Quanity - 1))) { 
                gDraw.DrawLine(Red_Pen, Column_Count, 0, Column_Count, Tile_Grid.Height);
            }
            gDraw.DrawString((i+1).ToString(), new Font("Arial", Column_Seperation_Size / 5), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), Column_Count, 0, new StringFormat());
        } 

        gDraw.Dispose();
        WriteLog("End");

    }
```

Comment: Additionally, When I try and draw more lines, this occurs. I'm not to sure but I plan to add horizontal lines as well.


[image](https://imgur.com/a/PTN8tTZ)

Comment: I can't even find where you use the `gDraw.MeasureString`... So I can't help you

Comment: You're specifying the string position using `Column_Count, 0` as the `x, y` coordinates. What would you want the coordinates to be for your desired outcome? You're also incrementing `Column_Count` _before_ you use it to draw the string.

Comment: I don't understand, what is wrong with the images, and what would you like it to do instead?

Comment: The `DrawString(... x, y)` method uses coordinates, which you have to calculate propertly. Looking at screenshot it seems you can simply add negative enough offset to fix it.

Comment: sLw Sinatr RobinBennett MattJones
I appreciate the comments but bwing has resolved this for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to measure the string and subtract that from your x position to move the numbers into the previous column.

```
var number = (i+1).ToString();
var emSize = Column_Seperation_Size / 5;
var font = new Font("Arial", emSize)
var size = gDraw.MeasureString(number, font);
var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
g.DrawString(number, font, brush, Column_Count - size.Width, 0);
```